# Select query with regular expression - MySql

Tags: regex, select, mysql

I want to select records if a particular column has numbers in its name.

Table 1

```
ID   EmpCode    EmpName
1    1C         Name1
2    2C         Name2
3    C3         Name3
4    CD         Name4
5    CD         Name4
6    C6D        Name6
7    7CD        Name7
```

I need to select records 1,2,3,6,7 based on EmpCode. How can this be performed?

**EDIT:** EmpCode can have number in any position

Comment: You mean, you want to select all rows where EmpCode starts with a digit? Please be a little more specific.

Comment: @fredley Sorry! pl look at my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE EmpCode REGEXP '[0-9]'
```

Or alternatively, if you want to check for 'starts with a digit' instead of 'contains a digit':

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE EmpCode REGEXP '^[0-9]'
```

Edit: REGEXP (not REGEX) is the correct function name...