# How to find the last name from a table in sql which contain only numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am preparing SQL interview questions from the internet and I am stuck at the following question .

```
Question: Select Last Name from employee table which contain only numbers

Answer: Select * from EMPLOYEE where lower(LAST_NAME) = upper(LAST_NAME)
```

I have copied the answer from the internet but I am unsure about the reason behind this answer

In my understanding, the question states that I have to select the last name which contain only numbers meaning those names which have numeral values ? Is the question asking us to calculate the numeral values (ASCII value) of last name? Let me know if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh but everywhere on the internet, the answer is same.

Comment: @Abhilash pointed out one of the flaws of this query

Comment: Also, if using a case insensitive collation (as is usual) then this simply won't work. Either way, it's a daft answer, but sometimes the internet's like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select * from EMPLOYEE where LAST_NAME REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

The question is to find all the rows where column `LAST_NAME` has only numbers. You don't have to calculate the ASCII values of last name. You can use the above query for this. It uses regular expression to find the required rows.

Comment: I have a question. Suppose if we are creating a table with then  name persons. CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. Consider this one. I have a question. Suppose if we are creating a table with the name persons and in the persons table there is a column name Last Name. In the table,  I have declared the data type of Last Name as varchar then by the general rule can we add numeral value in the Last Name column ?  I believe yes and how is that possible ?                                                                                     `CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);`

Comment: Yes we can add numeral value in varchar column using a simple insert query. The numeric value is implicitly converted to `varchar` type.

Comment: Also can you explain little bit about this expression '^[0-9]+$' ?

Comment: It's a regular expression for matching string at both start( ^) and end ($) of string. Each character inside string should be numeric( [0-9] ). There should be at least 1 numeric character in string (+)

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have to pick last names which have only numbers like `1234`.
The answer works if lastname contains only alphabets and numbers. Because if there are any letters then their upper and lower case won't be equal. But this does not consider the case in which last name may include other characters like !# etc

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code snippet:

```
Select * from EMPLOYEE where ASCII(lower(LAST_NAME)) = ASCII(upper(LAST_NAME))
```

Please check added ASCII keyword.
This will give you ASCII equivalent to `LAST_NAME`. If `LAST_NAME` is only have numbers the uppercase and lowercase must be same and ASCII equivalent also. But if `LAST_NAME` is having alphabets the ASCII equivalent is not same for Uppercase and Lowercase.

Thanks and Regards,
Ashish Mayekar

Comment: To critique another answer, please use a comment. (Requires 50 reputation which you can earn by posting useful answers and questions.)

Answer (score 0):

I think they treat the rows for which the `LAST_NAME` field contain only numbers as rows with insane values (because normally a last name should not contain just numbers).  The query is a trick to quickly identify those rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to check if the column value is matching the criteria. For example check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3759401/3503187) and similar questions on SO.